# jQuery Loudev multiselect is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a nice multi select field by using the [loudev](http://loudev.com/) multi-select.js I followed the steps on the page, but nothing happens - only a normal multiple `<select>` is shown. The paths to multi-select.css and jquery.multi-select.js are OK.

I can't figure what's wrong:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
      <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
    </select>
    <script src="/js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#my-select').multiSelect({});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above is working perfectly fine. You need to click on the CTRL key and make multiple selections. Do you want to see the selected items in a separate box on the right as shown on the developer's website ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>

<select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
  <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
  <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
  <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
  <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
  <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
</select>
<script src="js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $('#my-select').multiSelect({});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you made a slight mistake in the placement of the css and js files. Note that I removed the leading slash in front of the JS and CSS file and it is working fine for me. I assume you have the following directory structure

- HTML file
- js/ js file inside here
- css/ css file inside here

Comment: Exactly, I want to see the right box with the selected elements.

Comment: Check the change I have made in the code above, there was an extra forward-slash in your code and I believe your HTML file and the folders for JS and CSS are on the same level in the file hierarchy.

Comment: As I mentioned the paths were OK. Even with your version it was not working. I found the problem however thanks to your assurance that it's working at your side. Please check my answer. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I found my problem - it's because I'm using `https://` to load the page. In such case the links to `jQuery` should be also `https` otherwise the browser ignores them:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thanks to Rahul Kadukar and his answer to point me that the code is overall OK.